Why does TypeScript infer a different type when using T extends unknown[] vs T extends (number)[]?
I'm trying to understand why TypeScript infers different types in the following cases:
Case 1:
declare function Test<T extends unknown[]>(values: [...T]): T;
const test = Test([1, 2, 3]); // The inferred type is: [number, number, number]

Case 2:
declare function Test<T extends (number)[]>(values: [...T]): T;
const test = Test([1, 2, 3]); // The inferred type is: [1, 2, 3]

Why does TypeScript infer differently depending on the type parameter provided?
What is the reasoning behind this behavior?

I do not know why this is happening so this is a non answer.
But if you also want a solution you can use the const keyword like this:
declare function Test<const T extends unknown[]>(values: [...T]): T;
So the answer would probably be that it doesn't try to resolve further if it's not "instructed" to do so. But someone else probably knows better.

The rules for inferring literal/nonliteral types are mostly laid out in ms/TS#10676. See the linked q/a above for more information.
